# Android RunTime Permission not granting other permission in the same group

Tags: android, permissions

If i request two Permissions from same Group(Ex READ_CONTACTS , WRITE_CONTACTS) one after another the permission dialog asks the user to accept the permission from same group twice, however the documentation mentions if i accept a permission from same group, android automatically grants rest of the permissions in that group.

ex code:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) currentContext,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACT},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
```

as it should work a dialog appears requesting the permission,
however it appears again if i call the following code

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) currentContext,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACT},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
```

so a dialog for permissions from same group appears twice.
Is there a way where i can show only single dialog for permission of same group if i request them in the above fashion ie individually and not together?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says :

> The dialog box shown by the system describes the permission group your
>   app needs access to; it does not list the specific permission. For
>   example, if you request the READ_CONTACTS permission, the system
>   dialog box just says your app needs access to the device's contacts.
>   The user only needs to grant permission once for each permission
>   group. If your app requests any other permissions in that group (that
>   are listed in your app manifest), the system automatically grants
>   them. When you request the permission, the system calls your
>   onRequestPermissionsResult() callback method and passes
>   PERMISSION_GRANTED, the same way it would if the user had explicitly
>   granted your request through the system dialog box.

That mean that only one alert will be shown for group but you have to request each permissions of this group.

So you should request several permissions in same time :

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) currentContext,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACT, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACT},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
```

**EDIT**

To check if permission is already granted you have to use :

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: Im aware of that and since im dynamically fethching permissions from my manifest, calling them at the same time works but gives unwanted behaviour when declined ex how  can i check if the permission is already granted if i call them at the same time ?

Comment: Suppose that i have multiple permissions as you described some of them are of different group, then if i decline a permission the callback asks again and the new request from different group is drawn behind it that gives me a lot of problems.

Comment: The good behaviour is not to fetch permissions from manifest but ask for it when you need it. If you really want to check permissions in your way, make a static method that return group from permissions.